# Postgres JSONB to Oralce BLOB via Java

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, oracle

Getting given below error while loading  Postgres JSONB data into Oracle BLOG data type column.

```
SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type]]

Postgres SQL type is JSONB -jdoc
Oralce SQL Type  is BLOB   -jdoc
```

Refer the given below Code.

```
import java.sql.Blob;
@Data
Employee{

private Blob jdoc;

}
```

Row mapper

```
@Bean("employee_RowMapper")
    public RowMapper employee_entityRowMapper() {
        return new RowMapper<Employee>(){
            @Override
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                
                
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                System.out.println("JDOC is "+rs.getString("jdoc"));
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(rs.getString("jdoc"))) {
                Blob blobData = new SerialBlob(rs.getString("jdoc").getBytes());
                employee.setJdoc(blobData);
                }
                return employee;
            }  
        };
    }
```

SQLParameterSourceProvider

```
@Bean(name = "employee_entity_TableSqlParameterSourceProvider")
    public ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider employee_entityTableSqlParameterSourceProvider() {
        return new ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Employee>() {
 
            @Override
            public SqlParameterSource createSqlParameterSource(Employee item) {
                
                
                MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource= new MapSqlParameterSource();
                mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("jdoc",item.getJdoc(),Types.BLOB);
                return mapSqlParameterSource;
            }
        };
    }
```

Note : I have tried to load as string , while loading as string i am getting given below error.

ORA-01465: invalid hex number in oracle while using BLOB

i have tried with this function as well -  utl_raw.cast_to_raw in my update script- even though i am getting the same error.
[1]: [Oracle - Update BLOB with PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007290/oracle-update-blob-with-pl-sql)